# Plot wavefronts of Laguerre-Gaussian modes

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, physics, wavelet-analysis, wave-propagation

I am trying to plot wavefronts of Laguerre-Gaussian modes, and want to show the changing number of twists with the change in l values. If anyone has the code or any insights. Kindly help me about it. I want something like this.[image]

Comment: Similar to [202641](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202641/plot-of-laguerre-gaussian-wavefront).

Comment: @Syed , in that response twists are not changing with the number of l values.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please click on the question mark icon on the [page banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkyXu.png) and take the site `Tour`. Subsequently, post an on-topic question along with a minimal example and properly formatted Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: @Qubit From the first looking twists are changing  on the picture from my answer on 202641. Maybe you mean something else? :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank You for your response. I am referring to the number of twists like there are same number of twists in l=1 and l=2 both.

Comment: This is periodic function, so picture shows one period only. Do you need picture with `l` periods?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes exactly. Actually, I need to show Orbital Angular Momentum equals to L=ℏ. Where  being the number of twists.., Also, I have some basic questions regarding your code, can I have your email?

Comment: @Qubit Please, see my answer. My email address is available at  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379722005277?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to reproduce $l$ periods on $(0, 2\pi)$ can be modified from our answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202641/plot-of-laguerre-gaussian-wavefront) as follows

```
LG[r_, \[Phi]_, p_, l_, w_, 
   z_] := (Sqrt[(2 p!)/(\[Pi] (p + Abs[l])!)] 1/
     w E^(-r^2/w^2) ((r Sqrt[2])/w)^Abs[l] LaguerreL[p, Abs[l], 
     2 r^2/w^2] E^(I l \[Phi] + I z));
LGA[r_, p_, l_, w_, z_] := 
  Sqrt[(2 p!)/(\[Pi] (p + Abs[l])!)] 1/w E^(-r^2/w^2) ((r Sqrt[2])/w)^
    Abs[l] LaguerreL[p, Abs[l], 2 r^2/w^2];

{Table[Module[{l = L, p = 0, w = 1}, 
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[l u] Sin[v], Sin[Abs[l] u] Sin[v], l u}, {u, 
      0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, 
       Hue[Abs[LG[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], p, l, w, z]]]], 
     Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
     PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> Row[{"l = ", l}], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All] // 
    Quiet], {L, {-2, -1, 1, 2, 3}}], 
 Table[Module[{l = L, p = 0, w = 1}, 
   DensityPlot[
     Arg[LG[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], p, l, w, 0]], {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50,
      ColorFunction -> Hue] // Quiet], {L, {-2, -1, 1, 2, 3}}], 
 Table[Module[{l = L, p = 0, w = 1}, 
   DensityPlot[
     Abs[LGA[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], p, l, w, 0]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, 
     ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All] // Quiet], {L, {-2, -1, 
    1, 2, 3}}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]